# That vs Which (Solved using Gerund)

Tags: american-english, british-english

Apologies for re-opening a discussion on this topic, nevertheless, I'd like to hear your opinion on this. Take this sentence:

> There are ethical reasons **that** may lead John to opt for this choice.

My impression is that if in a sentence you can safely replace "that" with a gerund, then it's correct to use "that" (instead of which):

> There might be ethical reasons **leading** John to opt for this choice.

I just wonder if this approach could be an easier shortcut for choosing between that/which.

Thanks!

Comment: It's really of no consequence whether the relative clause can be replaced with a gerund-participial clause. It is a free choice here between "that" and "which", despite the silly ban on integrated _wh-_ relatives. There is no difference in meaning or in the syntax, other than what follows from "that" not being a pronoun, of course.

Comment: I prefer the “*which, by the way,*” substitution test because it more clearly gets at the restrictive/non-restrictive clause distinction.

Comment: The two sentences do not mean the same thing. One says there might be reasons, the other says there definitely are. That is not the same thing. I don't like how this question is treating language like some kind of math problem to solve. The language is perfectly fine, leave it to its own devices. You can say *that*, or you can say *which*, and it's not something to work your way around in the process changing everything else, including what you're actually saying.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment BillJ wrote:

> It's really of no consequence whether the relative clause can be replaced with a gerund-participial clause. It is a free choice here between "that" and "which", despite the silly ban on integrated *wh-* relatives. There is no difference in meaning or in the syntax, other than what follows from "that" not being a pronoun, of course.